# Node.js runtime with Rails on Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm trying to setup nginx + passenger + rails on ubuntu 14.04
The big requirement is to be able to install node packages w/o sudo and easiest way to achieve this is to install node for the user, not for the system afaik. So I tried to use nvm and it worked almost fine for assets compilation but when I try to hit the webpage there is an error in the passenger.log

```
`Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-rMZT8N.html
  Message from application: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
/var/www/something/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:48:in `autodetect'
```

Nodejs path is specified in the nginx.conf as following

`passenger_nodejs /home/deployer/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/node;`

but that doesn't help.

Update: full error message
App 7059 stdout:

```
App 7059 stderr: sh: 1:
App 7059 stderr: env: not found
App 7059 stderr:
App 7059 stdout: 
[ 2015-12-14 23:15:37.2157 22792/b596fb40 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/something/current: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 83f25d05
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-nee6cQ.html
  Message from application: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
  /var/www/something/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:48:in `autodetect'
  /var/www/something/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
  /var/www/something/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/www/something/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
  /var/www/something/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
  /var/www/something/releases/20151215040905/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/www/something/releases/20151215040905/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /var/www/something/releases/20151215040905/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /var/www/something/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /var/www/something/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
```

in contrary  `bundle exec rails s -e staging -b 0.0.0.0` works fine

Comment: Ages ago, but did you ever find a solution to this?